# How to swivel or transpose a data frame with n pivot points in Tidyverse or baseR?

Tags: r

My example data frame has 3 pivot points (x, y & z)

```
mydf = data.frame(x = 1:3, y = as.complex(1:3), z = c('i','j','k'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The desired output data frame will look like this:

```
  a b c    d    e    f g h i
1 1 2 3 1+0i 2+0i 3+0i i j k
```

I was looking for some efficient ways to achieve this in tidyverse or baseR. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
mydf = data.frame(x = 1:3, y = as.complex(1:3), z = c('i','j','k'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mydf<-data.frame(t(unlist(mydf)))
names(mydf)<-letters[1:length(names(mydf))]
mydf
```

and the output is

```
> mydf
  a b c    d    e    f g h i
1 1 2 3 1+0i 2+0i 3+0i i j k
```